# mvc5 model binding not working with dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view model class:

```
public class TankDurationViewModel
    {        
        public int selectedTankFactor { get;set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> tank_factor_list { get; set; }

        public double? myAnswer { get; set; }

        public TankDurationViewModel()
        {
            this.tank_factor_list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            this.tank_factor_list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "E", Value = "0.28" });
            this.tank_factor_list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "H", Value = "3.14" });
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.selectedTankFactor,Model.tank_factor_list,"Tank Type")
```

When I submit, my selectedTankFactor will not bind.  I will always be 0.  When i look at the formcollection, the selection is in the formcollection.  If I change the int selectedTankFactor into string, it will bind correctly but this it not what I want.  Does this relate to how i initialize the SelectListItem?  How do i get it to bind int?  The SelectListItem only take string for value.  Also how do i force user to choose a selection other than "Tank Type" before submitting?

Comment: show us controller method where this model is passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `selectedTankFactor` to a decimal and if you don't want the user to submit form without selecting tank type, add required validation to selectedTankFactor property. You also have to include jquery validate library for [client side validations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation).

```
[Required]
public decimal selectedTankFactor { get;set; }
```